# How to add scroll bar to a div when the parent div has hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a panels that are located on top of each other and in order to align them correctly, I needed to hide the overflow. However, each panel will need a scroll bar.
I can not apply a scroll bar since the parent panel has overflow as hidden.

In the below example, if you click on the button, the content of the back panel is larger than the size of the panel and needs a vertical scroll bar.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3hLv2os/3/)

```js
$(".backpnl").on('click tap', function() {
  
  $( '.frontPanel' ).toggleClass('active', 500)
});
```

```css
.mainPanel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frontPanel {
  background: #5D1202;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.backPanel {
  background: #280700;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
.backPanel:before{
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.frontPanel.active{
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainPanel">
  <div class="frontPanel">
    <h1>Front Panel</h1>
    <button class="backpnl">Click here</button>
  </div>
  <div class="backPanel">
    <h1>Back Panel</h1>
    <p>--- Text 1---</p>
    <p>--- Text 2---</p>
    <p>--- Text 3---</p>
    <p>--- Text 4---</p>
    <p>--- Text 5---</p>
    <p>--- Text 6---</p>
    <p>--- Text 7---</p>
    <p>--- Text 8---</p>
    <p>--- Text 9---</p>
    <p>--- Text 10---</p>
    <p>--- Text 11---</p>
    <p>--- Text 12---</p>
    <p>--- Text 13---</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can fix this so panels can have scroll bars if required?

Comment: remove 'position: relative's from mainpanel stylings and add 'overflow-y: auto'. Also add 'overflow-y: auto' inside front panel and backpanel

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar thanks but that ruins the whole structure.

Comment: Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/rensothearin/4x8wbaqg/6/